# Simply to minimum literals

Tags: boolean-algebra

F = AB'C + A'BC + ABD + CD' + D'

I started by doing D'(C+1) and reducing (C+1) into 1, resulting with D'1 which is just D'. I now have AB'C + A'BC + ABD + D', and cannot seem to find another way to reduce this further, though I know this cannot be the case. What am I missing? I tried to factor out a C from the first 2 terms, but did not know what to do after.

Answer (score 1):

Well $ABD+D'=AB+D'$, after which you can set the $D'$ off to the side and focus on the rest.

Next, distributing out the common term is a good plan.   However, recall $AB=ABC+AB$, so do that first and don't forget that $AB=AB+AB$.

Okay, that sounds like it is making things less simple, but look what happens.

$\begin{split}F ~=~& AB'C + A'BC + ABD + CD' + D'&\qquad\qquad&\text{as provided}\\=~ &AB'C+A'BC + ABD+D' &&\text{by absorption} \\= ~&AB'C+A'BC+AB&+D' &\text{by redundancy} \\=~&AB'C+A'BC+ABC+AB&+D' &\text{by absorption} \\= ~&(AB'+AB+A'B)C + AB~&+D'&\text{by distribution}\\=~&(AB'+AB~+~AB+A'B)C + AB~&+D'&\text{by idempotence} \\ =~&\text{well, you can take it from here.}\end{split}$

---

> Im confused about how you made ABD+D' become AB+D'. Did you seperate the D from AB to have (D+D') because even then it would just be 1.

It's by the redundancy rule.
$$\begin{split}ABD+D' &= (AB+D')(D+D')\qquad & \text{distribution}\\ &= (AB+D')1 &  \text{inversion}\\ & = AB+D' & \text{identity}\end{split}$$

---

Remember your Boolean Algebra
$$\begin{array}{|r:l:l:l|}\hline \text{Law} & \text{AND} &\text{OR}\\\hline
1 & \text{Identity} & {1A=A} & 0+A=A\\\hdashline
2 & \text{Annihilation} & 0A=0 & 1+A=1\\\hdashline
3 & \text{Inversion} & {AA'=0} & {A+A'=1} \\\hdashline
4 & \text{Double Inversion} &  (A')'=A & (A')'=A \\\hdashline
5 & \text{Idempotence} & AA=A & A+A = A\\\hdashline
6 & \text{Commutation} & AB=BA & A+B=Ba\\\hdashline
7 & \text{Association} & (AB)C {=A(BC)\\=ABC} & (A+B)+C{=A+(B+C)\\=A+B+C}\\\hdashline
8 & \text{Distribution} & A(B+C)=AB+AC & A+BC = (A+B)(A+C)\\\hdashline
9 & \text{Duality} & (AB)'= A'+B' & (A+B)'=A'B'\\\hline
10 &\text{Absorption} & A(A+B)=A & A+AB=A\\\hdashline
11 & \text{Redundancy} & A(A'+B)=AB & A+A'B=A+B\\\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Im confused about how you made ABD+D' become AB+D'. Did you seperate the D from AB to have (D+D') because even then it would just be 1. @Graham Kemp

Comment: @Kytex Distribute then Inversion (and Identity).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use K-Map to solve this equation.
The end equation after simplification will be

A'B+AB'+AD+D'